# Doctrine/DQL returning form values as DQL result during validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my system, I can specify 2 week period bookings in high seasons, so if two people lower in the family hierarchy of two brothers want to book the same period in a high season precedence rules apply.

I need to get the period booking of the contact chosen in the form, so I added the following code to my validate function in a validator(1 is used for testing):

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {

   $PB = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Period')->getPBForContact(1);

   var_dump($PB);
   die();
```

Here is the repository code for the corresponding function:

```
public function getPBForContact($Id){

  $em = $this->getEntityManager();
  $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT PB FROM AppBundle:Period PB JOIN PB.contact C WHERE C.id = :Id AND PB.draft = FALSE')->setParameter('Id', $Id);
  $PB = $query->getSingleResult();        

  return $PB;

}
```

The trouble is that when I dump the period booking the output given is the dates on the edit form and not the ones recorded in the database. When I specify the columns in the DQL I am given the start and end dates from the database records, but I no longer have an object this way. Also, when I use the other contact's id it gives me the correct dates for that contact's period booking.

Why is it returning the entered form values when they haven't been saved? What can I do to get the database values and not the form values?

I am using Symfony 2.7 and Doctrine.

Comment: I found the solution is to detach the entity in the controller and merge it if the form passes validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because doctrine uses the [identity map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern) for the loaded objects. You can't simply work with the two version of the same entity. The solution depends on many factors. For example you can clone entity before handling the form and work with the copy.